# Applying the visitor pattern for detecting cycles in a graph

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

i need to detect if in a directed graph there is a cycle , something likes the topological sort , but i wanna use the visitor pattern.. Do you have some ideas ? I can use the arraylist of nodes , and edges or other structures (not array) .

Comment: Show us some code. I don't see how the visitor pattern has anything to do with the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Graph problems are often solved with a DCEL as underlying datastructure http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list I also don't see how a visitor pattern would help here.

Comment: I don't have the code with me .. My graph is a composite graph , there is the first node ,the intermediate nodes , and the last node. The graph , indeed, is a node that memorize the adjacent nodes and the incoming and outgoing edges (the first node have only outgoing edges , and the last node only the incoming edges) .. The visitor has to start from the first node pass to the intermediate nodes and check the cycle .. Sorry for the bad English..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visitor pattern really can't achieve such a thing in its purest form.

Remember that a visitor pattern typically has the "visitor" travelling the web of objects, but the web of objects "directing" the visitor.  Since the visitor is effectively path-unaware, it prevents certain kinds of breakage.

[from the wikipedia example of the Visitor pattern (in Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

```
class Car implements CarElement {
    CarElement[] elements;
 
    public Car() {
        //create new Array of elements
        this.elements = new CarElement[] { new Wheel("front left"), 
            new Wheel("front right"), new Wheel("back left") , 
            new Wheel("back right"), new Body(), new Engine() };
    }
 
    public void accept(CarElementVisitor visitor) {     
        for(CarElement elem : elements) {
            elem.accept(visitor);
        }
        visitor.visit(this);    
    }
}
```

note the `Car` accept method.  It ensures that all the sub-elements of the car are covered, encapsulating navigation, yet exposing the ability to apply external functions against the entire data structure.

Since your code *requires* knowledge of how the data structure is wired together, the visitor pattern is poorly suited to the task.  If a visitor encounters a circular data structure, the future visitors will get stuck in the same loop, not visiting *some* of the data, breaking the contract between the `Visitor` and the `VisitAcceptors`.

Now you might be able to somewhat achieve the goal, provided you had "possibly circular" links in the visiting path not followed. You'd still have to ensure all nodes of the graph were followed in the visiting path, just by other branches of the visiting path.  Then your visitor would basically become a large collection of nodes that could be hit by the non-travelled back links, but by the time you implemented such an odd solution, you'd wonder why you bothered with the visitor part.

Comment: It's sad to see this as the accepted answer. Do a quick search on Visitor Pattern, cycles, or go read the bible: Gang of Four. Totally wrong. Not sure what 'the purest form' is. I would favor Visitor in situations like this for exactly that reason: you construct a composite of types, not just collections of random data.